# Linear algebra intersecting, coincide, no solution question

Tags: linear-algebra

Correct me if I am wrong on this.

Taking a system of equations

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
-7x-2y=14\\ 
6x+6y=18
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I can set it up in matrix form of
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -7 & -2 & 14 \\
        6 & 6 & 18
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Which can be calculated down to
   \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -4 \\
        0 & 1 & 7
        \end{bmatrix}
Thus making the system intersect $$ (-4,7) $$

Now if I take a system like
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
4x+2y=6\\ 
8x+4y=12
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I can set it up in matrix form of
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4 & 2 & 6 \\
        8 & 4 & 12
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Which can be calculated down to
   \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1 & 3 \\
        0 & 0 & 0
        \end{bmatrix}

Does that mean that system has infinitely many solutions? On the other side if I get a system other than that where the matrix into the first case or 2nd case have no solutions?

Comment: Yes to all of your questions. For your second system, you may choose freely $x$, and then take $y = 3 - 2 x$. A system with no solutions will be for instance $$\begin{cases}x + y = 0\\x + y = 1\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct. Note that for the [Rouché-Capelli's theorem](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjArP6FzJjLAhUECywKHQpcAokQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fit.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTeorema_di_Rouch%25C3%25A9-Capelli&usg=AFQjCNEnbwpXdkZd677QzOQMkbh_yPz7ig&bvm=bv.115339255,d.bGg) your linear system have solutions. In the first linear system the rank of this matrix is equal $2$ $$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -4 \\
        0 & 1 & 7
        \end{bmatrix}$$ and equal to the rank of this matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 
        \end{bmatrix}$$ The dimension of the solutions in genearal is given by $\infty^{n-r}$ wher $n$ indicates the number of incognites while $r$ the rank of the matrix